# docker for windows equivalent for "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I'm trying to control the host docker service from inside a container.

With Linux host and Linux container that is usually done like this:
`docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine`

I now want to achieve the same with a `Docker for Windows` host and a Linux container.

If tried quite a lot of things, mostly using `DOCKER_HOST` with varying IP's like `10.75.0.1:2375` (IP of docker VM), `172.17.0.1:2375` (container IP) and `0.0.0.0:2375` as well as `192.168.178.xxx:2375` (host IP).

But apparently nothing responds on port `2375` or `2376` which I checked with something like:
`docker run -ti --rm alpine /bin/sh -c "apk add -U nmap && nmap -Pn 10.72.0.1 -p 2375-2376"`

At this point I'd like to know if this is even possible with Docker for Windows. Most information I found concerns `docker-machine / VirtualBox` combinations.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Comment: @kaylum sure, which is why there is a `docker` tag ...

Comment: It is pretty simple to use docker on windows too now a days. Please install later version of docker.

Comment: @Rao yes, I know. I'm using the latest version. This is about a specific problem as described above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine when running Linux containers using Docker for Windows too (but not when running Windows containers). Just ensure that your shell won't rewrite paths or similar.

Comment: OMG, that was of course the only variant I never even attempted, because we all know Windows does not have `/var/run/docker.sock`. In hind side it is obvious, as the docker host does run in a VM and not in Windows itself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Perhaps the docker for windows documentation should be extended by this point.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't know what the answer is. Are you saying that it's the exact same command whether on Linux or Windows? Thanks

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy That's what they're saying. But it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: @GabrielBB, it works for me. I use -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged. The "--privileged" was necessary for me. My Docker host is on Windows and I'm accessing it from inside Linux containers.

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy Wow, not even with --privileged is working for me. I opened this issue yesterday: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4642

Comment: @GabrielBB, I created a GitLab repo for you to clone and test, which connects a Linux Docker container (in which you can develop your code with VS Code) to your Windows Docker host. Hope it helps!  https://gitlab.com/mccarthysean/develop-inside-linux-docker-container-on-windows-10-host

Comment: I believe you will need to install WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) for this to work the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how SO works so if necroposting is frowned upon then sorry. I also don't use docker on windows but this thread came up during my search for setting up portainer. I figured out the thing that I wanted to figure out and on first login portainer gave me this warning:

```
 Ensure that you have started the Portainer container with the following Docker flag:
-v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" (Linux).
or
-v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine (Windows).
```

So, there you go. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer by @friism:

> Just ensure that your shell won't rewrite paths or similar.

This was happening to me within Git Bash on Windows. The solution, in this case, was to prefix all absolute paths with an extra slash (`/`) to disable the automatic path rewriting done by Git Bash. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50608818/4135063))