# Docker mounted volume adds ;C to end of windows path when translating from linux style path

Tags: docker

I've found some interesting weirdness when trying to mount a docker image on windows.

I created a `.sh` script that does a mount of the project folder to run our developer environment image. I want one script that every dev can run, regardless of their machine. All it does is runs docker with the current project folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker run -it --rm -v D:\my\project\folder:/wkDir $IMAGE_TAG yarn dev
```

Runs okay. Now the plan is to call this script from `npm`, so I'd like this to work relative to the current folder. Let's try another version.

`docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/wkDir $IMAGE_TAG yarn dev`

Fails with:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from 
daemon: Mount denied:
The source path "D:/my/project/folder;C"
doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.
```

Wat. What's `;C` and where did it come from?

So I do `echo $PWD` which gives me `/d/my/project/folder`.

Interesting, so `$PWD` resolves to the correct path in linux path format, and it seems like docker is trying to translate from that to the correct windows path, except there's this `;C` that appears out of nowhere. And the `\` are `/`...

What exactly is going on here?

I get the same result in VSCode's terminal git bash and powershell.

Update: I noticed that running the `.sh` in VSCode's powershell terminal, opens a separate `cmd.exe` console window which seems to run the script in git bash. So this might be a git bash issue.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

So with some extra digging I found these three threads, related to git-bash mucking up docker mount:

https://forums.docker.com/t/weird-error-under-git-bash-msys-solved/9210
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029#issuecomment-250412919

When I look up mingw's documentation on the path conversion git-bash is using, I find this table of syntax:
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion

One of which outputs in the format: `x;x;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\x`. Note the `;C` in it. If git-bash is trying to be clever, stuffing up the syntax and outputting a path with this format, this would explain it.

Solution is to escape the path conversion, using by prefixing with `/`. So the working docker command to run docker from git-bash with present working directory:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /${PWD}:/wkDir $IMAGE_TAG yarn dev
```

Comment: I found that I had to additionally wrap the path into a string so `"/${PWD}"`

Comment: `$ docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /$(pwd):/var/www -w //var/www node npm start`

I eventually found that I had to use the leading slash with parenthesis instead of braces. Also, with the working directory I needed two leading slashes.

FYI: this is the command I needed for [Docker for Web Developers on Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/docker-web-development)

Comment: This worked for me (on Windows 10 git bash):
docker run --name my-wordpress -v "/${PWD}/wordpress":/wordpress_sources -p 80:80 -d k <image_name>

Comment: Life saving.  Windows10 and git-bash here, took me a long while to try mounting volume without using docker-compose, until I see this post. Now this works: `docker run --rm -v /${PWD}/migrations:/flyway/sql --network xxx_default flyway`. Thank you.

Comment: LIFE. SAVER. +1000000

Comment: On Windows 10 (v1909) with Docker 3.1 and Git Bash 4.4.23 - mkdir works without adding the "/" `mkdir -p ${PWD}/data`
However, it is required for docker run - `docker run -v "/${PWD}/data":/opt/data image`

Comment: Note that if you want an absolute path (which already starts with `/`) you need a second leading `/`  like so: `docker run -it  "$CONTAINER_ID" "//bin/bash"`

Answer (score 25):

Mounting the current directory into a Docker container in Windows 10 from Git Bash (MinGW) may fail due to a POSIX path conversion. Any path starting with `/` is converted to a valid Windows path.

```
touch test.txt
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data busybox ls -la /data/test.txt
# ls: C:/Git/data/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

### Escape the POSIX paths by prefixing with `/`

To skip the path conversion, all POSIX paths have to be prefixed with the extra leading slash (`/`), including `/$(pwd)`.

```
touch test.txt
docker run --rm -v /$(pwd):/data busybox ls -la //data/test.txt
# -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Jun 22 23:45 //data/test.txt
```

In Git Bash the path `//data/test.txt` is not converted and in Linux shells `//` (leading double slash) is ignored and treated the same way as `/`.

### Disable the path conversion

Disable the POSIX path conversion in Git Bash (MinGW) using `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV` environment variable.

The path conversion can be disabled at the command level:

```
touch test.txt
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data busybox ls -la /data/test.txt
# -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Jun 22 23:45 /data/test.txt
```

The path conversion can be disabled at the shell (or system) level:

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
touch test.txt
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data busybox ls -la /data/test.txt
# -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Jun 22 23:45 /data/test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution as escaping didn't work for me, while disabling the path conversion did.

Comment: Maybe the disabling of the path conversion should be listed first, for lazy people who just copy/paste the first solution :p
Also, for me the command-level variable setting did not work on Git Bash in Windows10: "bash: MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1: command not found"
So the proper solution seems to be the one with export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was **simply to include a closing slash `/` at end of any paths**.

E.g. instead of

`/opt/apache-atlas-2.0.0/bin/atlas_start.py`

...use

`/opt/apache-atlas-2.0.0/bin/atlas_start.py/`

Comment: This is very misleading. A path ending with slash means it's a directory. It doesn't make sense to add a slash after a python file (or any file which is not a directory) !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on git bash and not command prompt.
You can instead

```
docker run -it --rm -v "/${PWD}/D:\my\project\folder":/wkDir $IMAGE_TAG yarn dev
```

Comment: just `-v "c:\my\path":wkdir` is enough in Docker Desktop 3.2.2

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `winpty`, note that it doesn't respect these env variables: https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/issues/125

There is a [workaround](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/issues/125#issuecomment-473446719) which writes arguments to a temporary file, and uses `xargs -0a` to pass them to docker. This way the path doesn't get mangled up.

```
docker() {
    realdocker='/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker'
    export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*"
    printf "%s\0" "$@" > /tmp/args.txt
    winpty bash -c "xargs -0a /tmp/args.txt '$realdocker'"
}
```

There is also a more complete and robust wrapper in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikeslattery/9b618669b63fe9dc984d5924bbb3aaee). (I'm not sure what is the policy regarding copying source code here without any knowledge of the license.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v %cd%:/wkDir $IMAGE_TAG yarn dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had the same issue. Depending on if you are using Git Bash this command works(using nginx as an example):

```
docker container run --name container-name -v \`pwd -W\` /html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8000:80 -d nginx
```

Of course you can specify the port and directory as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Straight worked for me below. Just don't use dynamic variable.

```
docker run --rm -u root -p 8080:8080 -v jenkins-data/:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock/:/var/run/docker.sock -v /Users/<YOUR USER NAME>/:/home jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on MSYS2 (Mingw64).
After reading [Filesystems Paths - MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/) I added `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL='*'` before `docker run` in my command line to prevent all arguments from being such "converted" and that makes it.

Example (MSYS2 Mingw64):

```
$> MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL='*' docker run --rm -d -v my_volume:/var/lib/my_volume myimage
```

Indeed Mingw tries to be clever by converting what's look like Unix paths to Windows paths for you. But as we can read: *while this is helpful in many cases it's also not perfect and in corner cases converts arguments that look like Unix paths while they are not, or detects lists of Unix paths where there are none.* Undeniably that's the case in this `docker` command.

You can also finely tune which arguments are "converted" or not by specifying which options are to be excluded, please read the link.