# The source path is not found and not know to docker

Tags: docker

```
 $ winpty docker run -it -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd):/app -w "/app" 
 microsoft/aspnetcore-build /bin/bash
 C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: Error response from 
 daemon: Mount denied:
 The source path "C:/Users/Nutcha;C"
 doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.
 See 'C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe run --help'.
```

My current workspace is in Document folder but this error happen what I suppose to do. I use Gitbash.

Thank you

Comment: Your question has been answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608301/docker-mounted-volume-adds-c-to-end-of-windows-path-when-translating-from-linux